# How to select only IDs that has a record value in common SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I just couldn't work out this sql query, I've even searched but didn't come up with a correct solution. I know its simple but there's something I'm not getting right.

My question stands as: Say **Set_ID** and **Acc_No** are in different tables that is related by *Acc_ID*. How do I select only the **Set_ID** that contains the **Acc_No** (*1-1110*)?

So that from this...

```
 Set_ID | Acc_No
 ---------------
  25    | 1-1110
  25    | 1-1225
  100   | 1-1110
  100   | 1-5555
  126   | 1-1141
  126   | 1-1552
  150   | 1-1110
  150   | 1-1200
  201   | 1-1221
  201   | 1-1200
```

To this...

```
 Set_ID | Acc_No
 ---------------
  25    | 1-1110
  25    | 1-1225
  100   | 1-1110
  100   | 1-1555
  150   | 1-1110
  150   | 1-1200
```

Comment: You're using 2 different RDBMSs?

Comment: @Fabio, did you try the query provided in below answer? Let me know if you are facing any issues with the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to apply inner join on these 2 tables along with a condition on `SET_ID`.

As per description provided by you, I tried to create the 2 tables named `tbl_sets` and `tbl_accounts` and come up with below SQL query:

```
  SELECT S.Set_ID,A.Acc_No from tbl_sets S
  INNER JOIN tbl_accounts A
  ON S.Acc_ID = A.Acc_ID
  AND S.Set_ID in (SELECT Set_ID FROM tbl_sets ts INNER JOIN  tbl_accounts    ta ON  ts.Acc_ID = ta.Acc_ID WHERE ta.Acc_No = '1-1110')
```

Refer this demo for the complete table schemas and SQL query:

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae296/1)

Comment: @Strawberry, the subquery is needed to further refine the query so that it will return all the `Set_ID` - `Acc_No` combinations of those `Set_IDs`  who are paired with `Acc_No` -  **1-1110**.